# Justify text left and right

Tags: horizontal-alignment

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\title{asdfsadf}
\author{asdfasdf}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\everymath{\displaystyle} 

\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}



\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\fontsize{14pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING \\ SOMETHING}

\ \\[1.5cm]
\begin{spacing}{2}
{\fontsize{24.88pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING \\ SOMETHING}
\end{spacing}
\ \\[1.5cm]
\begin{center}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
A asodfih saodfihsaodfuhasoidfuhasoifduhasoifuhsaiofuhasoidfuhsa asd;fuhsa dfuh asufhd pasdfuhsapudfhsaidfuh saidfas iudfhgsaidfg saidfyg saiuyfg saoiyfg saioyfg sayigf syaiogf saiogf saiogf ysaiodgf saoigfysaiodgfyoaisdgf asoiygf saoiygf sayoidfg asoiydfg asoiydfg asoiydf g A asodfih saodfihsaodfuhasoidfuhasoifduhasoifuhsaiofuhasoidfuhsa asd;fuhsa dfuh asufhd pasdfuhsapudfhsaidfuh saidfas iudfhgsaidfg saidfyg saiuyfg saoiyfg saioyfg sayigf syaiogf saiogf saiogf ysaiodgf saoigfysaiodgfyoaisdgf asoiygf saoiygf sayoidfg asoiydfg asoiydfg asoiydf g A asodfih saodfihsaodfuhasoidfuhasoifduhasoifuhsaiofuhasoidfuhsa asd;fuhsa dfuh asufhd pasdfuhsapudfhsaidfuh saidfas iudfhgsaidfg saidfyg saiuyfg saoiyfg saioyfg sayigf syaiogf saiogf saiogf ysaiodgf saoigfysaiodgfyoaisdgf asoiygf saoiygf sayoidfg asoiydfg asoiydfg asoiydf g
\ \\[6cm]
{\fontsize{17.28pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING}
\\[0.5cm]
{\fontsize{14pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING \& SOMETHING}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

However I want the text under "Acknowledgements" to be justified left and right, ie, make it look like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change where to place `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\title{asdfsadf}
\author{asdfasdf}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}



\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\fontsize{14pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING \\ SOMETHING}

\ \\[1.5cm]
\begin{spacing}{2}
{\fontsize{24.88pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING \\ SOMETHING}
\end{spacing}
\ \\[1.5cm]
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
A asodfih saodfihsaodfuhasoidfuhasoifduhasoifuhsaiofuhasoidfuhsa asd;fuhsa dfuh asufhd pasdfuhsapudfhsaidfuh saidfas iudfhgsaidfg saidfyg saiuyfg saoiyfg saioyfg sayigf syaiogf saiogf saiogf ysaiodgf saoigfysaiodgfyoaisdgf asoiygf saoiygf sayoidfg asoiydfg asoiydfg asoiydf g A asodfih saodfihsaodfuhasoidfuhasoifduhasoifuhsaiofuhasoidfuhsa asd;fuhsa dfuh asufhd pasdfuhsapudfhsaidfuh saidfas iudfhgsaidfg saidfyg saiuyfg saoiyfg saioyfg sayigf syaiogf saiogf saiogf ysaiodgf saoigfysaiodgfyoaisdgf asoiygf saoiygf sayoidfg asoiydfg asoiydfg asoiydf g A asodfih saodfihsaodfuhasoidfuhasoifduhasoifuhsaiofuhasoidfuhsa asd;fuhsa dfuh asufhd pasdfuhsapudfhsaidfuh saidfas iudfhgsaidfg saidfyg saiuyfg saoiyfg saioyfg sayigf syaiogf saiogf saiogf ysaiodgf saoigfysaiodgfyoaisdgf asoiygf saoiygf sayoidfg asoiydfg asoiydfg asoiydf g
\begin{center}
\ \\[6cm]
{\fontsize{17.28pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING}
\\[0.5cm]
{\fontsize{14pt}{0}\selectfont SOMETHING \& SOMETHING}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you. On a related note, how can I make the margins on the left and right of the centered paragraph smaller?

Comment: @TrueTears Change the `left` and `right` values when loading `geometry`, e.g. `\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}`

Comment: Ah yes, what I mean is, how can I change the margin specifically for the environment in which the paragraph is in. Because changing it when loading geometry will change it for the entire document (This is only the first page), so I only want it applied for this paragraph and nothing else.

Comment: @TrueTears `\newgeometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}` before `\begin{titlepage}` and `\restoregeometry` after `\end{titlepage}`